# Remove IP with ip command in linux

Tags: networking, bash, ip, ubuntu-12.04

If I add two IPs like this:

```
ip addr add 1.1.1.1/24 dev eth2
ip addr add 1.1.1.2/24 dev eth2
```

and then I try to delete one of like this:

```
ip addr del 1.1.1.2/24 dev eth2
```

BOTH IPs will be deleted and I don't know how to handle it.

Any one knows how to solve it?

Comment: Your requuirement is not clear. Can you tell what is the expected output here?

Comment: I need to say ip just to delete one IP not both of them

Comment: Please add `ip addr show` output

Answer (score 31):

This happens because you use /24 network mask when delete. It is applied to address you input. Try the following:

`ip addr del 1.1.1.2/32 dev eth2`

The /32 mask defines exactly one host.

Comment: This does not work as I have gave the system /24 netmask not /32.

Comment: Try without netmask at all: `ip addr del 1.1.1.2 dev eth2`

Comment: Again it Delete both IPs!!

Comment: Strange. On my testing CentOS box deleting without netmask was successful. Though deleting with /24 also affected only one address. What distro are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Did you exactly used the same command I used?

Comment: Yeah. Exactly. Seems to be an Ubuntu-specific question.

Answer (score 15):

Deleting a primary IP address from an interface will, by default,  delete all other address on the same subnet.

This is a reply to a REHL bug [1136733](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1136733)  reported by the user lain who provided an answer on 12-Mar-13 ...

> You're adding multiple addresses in the same subnet, thus the second and
>   subsequent ones become secondaries. This can be seen in the "ip addr show"
>   output, note the keyword "secondary" next to those addresses.
>
> By default, when deleting a primary address, kernel deletes also all
>   respective secondaries.
>
> If you want one of the secondaries to be promoted to be a new primary on
>   primary deletion, set the net.ipv4.conf.eth9.promote_secondaries sysctl.

Comment: `sudo systemctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.promote_secondaries`
Unknown operation net.ipv4.conf.eth0.promote_secondaries.

Comment: @LaryxDecidua **systemctl** is entirely different command from **sysctl**

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an eth2 to check this on but it works correctly on eth0 and I see no reason why eth2 should be magical. I presume you're using `ip addr show dev eth2` as `ifconfig eth2` doesn't appear to show the additional addresses added by ip.

One thing I have noticed is that the order you create/delete the addresses is important. The second and subsequent addresses added within the same network will be deleted if the primary address is deleted. Consider ...

```
    inet 1.1.1.1/24 scope global eth0
    inet 1.1.2.3/24 scope global eth0
    inet 1.1.1.2/24 scope global secondary eth0
    inet 1.1.1.3/24 scope global secondary eth0
```

If you delete 1.1.1.1 then the 1.2 and 1.3 addresses will be deleted too. If you delete any other address then only that address will be deleted.

Comment: So, how can I delete first address without removing others?

Answer (score 1):

The [answer of @bvs](https://serverfault.com/a/638320/510168) pointed in exactly the right direction of the problem and solved it for me. Here, are some details on the precise commands. As for many the default interface is `eth0`, I am taking that in the following commands, which has to replaced by `eth2` for the original question.

For a temporary solution (until reboot) use

`sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.promote_secondaries=1`

for a permanent solution which persists after reboots create a file `/etc/sysctl.d/ip-promote.conf` (or other file name ending with `.conf`) with the following content:

```
# The following makes that a second IP on the eth0 interface
# is promoted as primary IP instead of being removed.
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.promote_secondaries=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

> ip addr del 1.1.1.2 dev eth2